# Mac system can't find Ruby file to execute

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I'm trying to execute my Ruby file that just prints out a string of text: this is literally the file:

```
puts "System Initialized"
```

but I keep getting an error every time I try it.

When I execute it, it looks like this:

```
My-Mac-mini:event_manager my_name$ ruby lib\event_manager.rb
```

The error message is as follows:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/crystalchoi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
 Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm pretty new to using a Mac when it comes to programming, and I'm following a tutorial to do this, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone can help me decipher this error message and let me know how to correct it or can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and to Ruby!  Does the specified library (`/usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib`) exist?  You can use `ls` to find out.

Comment: @JaredBeck - So I just checked and I could not find it at all.  I even just checked /usr/local/lib to see if I can see it in the list there, but no luck.

Do you know of a way to get this file and where I should place it (or install it)?

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby lib\event_manager.rb
```

Mac OS, like other *nix-based systems, uses `/` to separate the path components of files. Only Windows uses `\`. Instead use:

```
ruby lib/event_manager.rb
```

A Ruby tutorial isn't going to help a whole lot unless you understand the *nix command-line so you can move around and execute things, so I'd STRONGLY suggest you learn a lot more about how *nix works. Having developed on Linux for years, I have had to use my command-line knowledge just as much as my programming-language skills daily.

Comment: I actually tried doing that as well with the forward slash and I just get the same error message. :(

Comment: That's a different problem than using the wrong path separator. It looks like you're missing the gmp library which is part of the OpenSSL library. I don't know why RVM didn't install that for you. Did you follow the directions on [RVM's installation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) and [Ruby installation](http://rvm.io/rubies/installing) pages?

Comment: The tutorial that I used was from tutorials.jumpstartlabs.com.  They first tell me to run this code in Terminal --> "curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable".  After that's finished, after that it tells me to check the version of it (which tells me I have "1.25.33").  The next thing it tells me to install is --> "rvm install 2.1".  Which I did and if I try to run it again it says I already have it.  The next line it asks me to put in is "rvm requirements".  Also, just to give a heads up, I also have Homebrew installed as well.

Comment: I did not go to the RVM site you listed or the Ruby one either.  I will try and take a look at those and see if I can find hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: The RVM authors [specifically warn](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) about using any tutorial for installation other than their own site. They know what works and keep it updated, other people know what worked for their particular situation at that moment. "Note that that any outside tutorials are NOT supported whether they work or not. Tutorials are great, however we have spent massive amounts of man hours debugging the installation process. Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods."

Answer (score 0):

> > Does the specified library (/usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib) exist?
>
> I just checked and I could not find it at all.

GMP (libgmp) is an optional dependency of ruby.  When you installed ruby, it was configured to use GMP, but you don't have the library file (/usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib)

That's OK, you can get GMP ( The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library) from homebrew.

```
brew update
brew install gmp
```

You may need to re-install ruby afterward.

See https://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm where other people had the same problem.

**Advanced**

If you're compiling ruby the old school way (`./configure && make`) then you could try using the `--without-gmp` config. option.

See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8796